# Asp.net mvc get setten var from javascript with razor inside .cshtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Made a function which validates a form input, now can't figure out how to combine this with razor tho.

**Function**

```
// input validation
    if ($SectionSingInUp.hasClass('at-sign-up')) {
        correctInput = true;

        if ($displayName.val().length < 5 || $displayName.val().length > 20) {
            correctInput = false;
            errorMessage = '<br> <strong>Displayname</strong> minimal 5, maximal 20 characters';
        }
        if (!emailRex.test($emailSignUp.val())) {
            errorMessage += '<br> Invalid <strong>email</strong>';
            correctInput = false;
        }
        if (!passwordRex.test($passwordSignUp.val())) {
            errorMessage += '<br> <strong>Password</strong> isn\'t strong enough.';
            correctInput = false;
        }
    }

    if (!correctInput) {
        window.showOeps(errorMessage);
    } else {
        // razor -> create new user
        $signInUp.toggleClass('at-sign-up');
    }
```

**_AppLayout.cshtml**

```
@RenderBody()
@Html.Partial("_Remodal")
```

**Result (remodal popup)**
[image]

If the input is correct, I need to notice this with razor.
Inside the .cshtml, I need to get the result from the if/else js.. Not sure if this is possible. (just started on asp.net)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean _combine this with razor_? Razor is server side code and javascript is client side code. Is there any reason you not using standard MVC's validation features?

Comment: hey @StephenMuecke thanks for responce, I was told as to validate as much on the client side (is faster?), and optionally also on the server side (hacking reasons)? But it isn't possible to check if javascript is passed/failed?

Comment: You have been told wrong. You absolutely must validate on the server (any one can by pass your script and post whatever they want. Client side validation is just a nice bonus. MVC has all this out of the box - just apply validation attributes to you properties - eg `[Required]`, `[StringLength]` etc and include the relavant jquery scripts along with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for the properties and you get both client and server side validation in 1/10 of the code

Comment: Where is your Javascript located?  Is it in your partial view?  (NOTE: the .cshtml code only runs server side and produces HTML -- your JS code will not 'interact' directly with .cshtml

Comment: @StephenMuecke Big thanks for helping me out here, now I need where to search!

Comment: @DavidTansey javascript file? it is in the script directory, my _AppLatout.cshtml calls this script on the end (script src = ... ) Is is possible to run this on the server side?

Comment: Start with [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation) to get some understanding of what the validation features of MVC are, but if your just starting out, I strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the article and advise, started a empty mvc because I didn't understood what was generated (not my way to learn). I sometime watch a generated template tho, they use a very complex way to register a user.. wo and the article is very useful I see!!!